# Convert from string to Pyspark Schema

Tags: python, database, string, pyspark, schema

I have a pyspark database schema in form of a string:
Schema = "StructType([StructField('C_0_0', StringType(), True), StructField('C_0_1', DecimalType(10,6), True), StructField('C_0_2', StructType([StructField('C_1_0', StringType(), True), StructField('C_1_1', ArrayType(StringType(), True), True)]), True)])"

I want to convert it into pyspark databse schema type. How can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

1. Import the types package and execute the `eval()` function by passing the schema you have

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *

string_schema = "StructType([StructField('C_0_0', StringType(), True), StructField('C_0_1', DecimalType(10,6), True), StructField('C_0_2', StructType([StructField('C_1_0', StringType(), True), StructField('C_1_1', ArrayType(StringType(), True), True)]), True)])"

executed_schema = eval(string_schema)
```

2. Check the type of `executed_schema`

```
type(executed_schema)
```

Type: `<class 'pyspark.sql.types.StructType'>`

3. Now use this schema against the DataFrame you want

```
df = spark.read.format("any_format").schema(executed_schema).load("path/to/file")
df.show()
```